# In magento 2, How to get available sales rules value in the multiselect field in admin form

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

In magento 2, How to  get  available sales rules  value in the multiselect field in admin form

Expectation:

[image]

Comment: Is this a sales rules title?

Comment: yes, its sales rule title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below method to get available sales rules names in admin configuration

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<field id="list_mode" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>Shopping cart rule</label>
   <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\ConfigSource</source_model>
</field>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ConfigSource.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor/Module\Model;

class ConfigSource implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    protected $ruleFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory
    ){
        $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $rules = $this->ruleFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $data[] = [
            'value' => '',
            'label' => __('Please select')
        ];
        foreach ($rules as $key => $rule) {
            $data[$key] = [
                'value' => $rule->getRuleId(),
                'label' => $rule->getName()
            ];
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.